# Where can I download airchat?

Tags: wifi, security

I'm a penetration tester currently conducting a security test on our company's network, and have already verified most of the hosts on the network are secure. But I saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QPcQFhBRWk) I heard of this type of attack before and the company security department has agreed to check whether the network is vulnerable to this and if any client's windows systems have autoconnect on and connect to unsecure wifi networks. I already have airbase-ng on the linux system and it works, but I don't have airchat and using google searches I could not find the download link.

If anyone has a good link for airchat, or something like it (with dhcp server+iptables+dns) please post a download link.

Answer (score 1):

There's a link right in the YouTube video description. It seems to be downloadable from [this forum thread](https://wardriving-forum.de/forum/showthread.php?t=66648). There's also a [subversion repository](http://svn.gnoxter.ath.cx/airchat/trunk/) linked from the [tutorial](http://www.wardriving-forum.de/wiki/Airchat-Tutorial) but it doesn't seem to be reachable right now (it's on a dynamic IP, so it's possible it's the guy's home computer and is turned off).

Based on the video it seems like an interesting tool, but as with a lot of the grey hat software, a bit hard to get a hold of.